# Is Witten's proof of the positive mass theorem rigorous?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, general-relativity, dirac-operator, spinor

I noticed that the only official reason given for awarding Edward Witten the Fields medal was his 1981 proof of the positive mass theorem with spinors, so I was assuming that the proof was fully rigorous.

However, I came across this paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103921154 by Taubes and Parker which claims to make Witten's proof 'mathematically rigorous' and to justify assumptions which Witten made about Dirac operators.  Does this mean that the Witten proof is not rigorous, or is it just the case that there were some unjustified lemmas to clear up which do not affect the validity or rigour of the argument (similar to the case of Perelman's proof of the Poincaré conjecture, where some lemmas and slight gaps had to be filled in)?

I am just curious as I have never really heard of the Taubes-Parker paper so I was assuming that the Witten paper was fully rigorous.

Later: I realise now that this is a bit of a misleading question, as 'proofs' can in reality come in many different flavours and/or levels of rigour ie. all the i's dotted and t's crossed, or some things left unsaid or which still remain to be proved.

Comment: I think some clarification on what is meant by 'fully rigorous' would help, and possibly avoid some close votes -- questions like 'is xyz's proof of conjecture abc valid' are too opinion based, but if you could point to specific arguments/lemmas that appear nebulous for specific mathematical reasons it seems a good question. For example we could interpret 'fully rigorous' as 'being proved directly from the axioms of some set theory/logic' in which case the answer is obviously no, but this is not generally the bar for rigor in mathematics outside logic and set theory.

Comment: Following @AlecRhea’s good points, I’d suggest the most productive way to frame this question isn’t “Is Witten’s proof rigorous?” so much as “How rigorous was Witten’s proof, and what is its relationship to later more rigorous elaborations like Taubes–Parker?”  There is a spectrum different levels of rigour short of a full proof: a full sketch with some details missing; a sketch with most details omitted; a detailed outline; a heuristic argument which turns out to guide an eventual full proof; a heuristic argument that motivates the result but doesn’t form the basis of any proof…

Comment: @AlecRhea I think questions about the validity of the proof of conjecture abc are referring to Mochizuki, not xyz...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The positive mass theorem is more or less to do with the geometry of a type of positive scalar curvature condition.

Witten's work considers harmonic spinors, which are solutions to a certain linear elliptic system of partial differential equations. In his paper he presents a calculation which proves a rigidity theorem for harmonic spinors under a type of positive scalar curvature, directly comparable to Bochner's famous rigidity theorem for harmonic 1-forms in positive Ricci curvature. It is a little more complicated only since spinors are more complicated than differential forms.

Given the existence of a harmonic spinor with certain asymptotics, an integrated version of Witten's Bochner-type formula proves that the relevant positive scalar curvature condition implies the nonnegativity of the mass, now being expressed as the integral of the sum of squares of expressions built out of the harmonic spinor.

Witten's proof of the existence of such harmonic spinors is openly incomplete; he says "We have shown that the Dirac operator has no zero eigenvalue. Using this fact, we presume that standard methods can be used to yield" a key analytical step. The problem is existence of a Green's function for the relevant elliptic operator over noncompact spaces. Parker and Taubes gave a complete proof. I think it is not completely accurate to say that their proof only consists of "standard methods," since care is needed about weighted Sobolev spaces which can be somewhat delicate.

So I think it is inaccurate/misleading to put Witten's proof of positive energy theorem with some of his other works in terms of "inspiration and insight" for mathematics, or to just cite "origin in supergravity" (as Atiyah's laudatio does). His work here is a pretty direct and rigorous mathematical argument, in the vein of standard differential geometry. The gap is only due to his not being an expert in PDE methods. Even so he makes plausible that the relevant harmonic spinors exist. I think that a PDE expert reading his paper would likely even find it informally convincing.

As far as the Fields medal goes, I think some of his other work must have been more relevant. It's not hard to imagine someone else having discovered the main parts of Witten's proof, having to do with differential identities for spinors, with much less fanfare. The calculation relating the mass to the spinor is maybe the most striking part but I think many people (whether reasonably or not) would not regard it as a high point of mathematics (or whatever Fields medal is supposed to be about).

Answer (score 19):

You should probably read the conclusion (Section 6) of [Atiyah's laudatio](http://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/reinsch/phys105spr2014/files/Witten_Atiyah.pdf) on Witten work during the 1990 ICM (specifically, the positive mass theorem is treated in Section 3).

> **6. Conclusion**
>
> From this very brief summary of Witten's achievements it should be clear that
> he has made a profound impact on contemporary mathematics. In his hands
> physics is once again providing a rich source of inspiration and insight in
> mathematics. Of course physical insight does not always lead to immediately
> rigorous mathematical proofs but it frequently leads one in the right direction,
> and technically correct proofs can then hopefully be found. This is the case with
> Witten's work. So far his insight has never let him down and rigorous proofs, of
> the standard we mathematicians rightly expect, have always been forthcoming.
> There is therefore no doubt that contributions to mathematics of this order are
> fully worthy of a Fields Medal.

Comment: I have read it and do not doubt Witten's contributions to physics or to mathematics: I was asking specifically about the proof of the positive mass theorem which was given as the official reason on the citation.

Comment: The proof of positive mass theorem is treated in Part 3 of the laudatio. It is called a "outline", so actually some technical detail was missing, but the idea was completely correct.  That said, I do not know why only that result has been given as official reason for the prize, since the laudatio contains much more.

Comment: OK, maybe that was my confusion, as that is literally the only reason given and that has always seemed very strange to me.  I'm not saying that his proof of the positive mass theorem was not a very significant achievement.

Comment: @Tom : What do you mean by "literally the only reason given"? I don't think that the IMU or the Fields Medal Committee produces a piece of text for each medalist and declares that text, and only that text, to be the "official reason" for awarding the medal. No such "official citations" appear on the IMU website, for example. I suspect that if you ask any former committee member, they will say that the reasons for the choices are complicated, and that any public statement or press release is not intended to be a comprehensive statement of those reasons.

Comment: @TimothyChow For most years there are short citations for the fields medalists available on the IMU website. For instance, last years' are at https://www.mathunion.org/imu-awards/fields-medal/fields-medals-2018 I guess these are produced by the Fields Medal Committee, but maybe by someone else.

Comment: @TimothyChow  Of course these are not literally the only reasons (otherwise they would have to describe why every other potential candidate was not awarded the medal), but the authors clearly try to describe the recipient's most important work. In most cases they are successful - i.e. people who are famous for one or two theorems have those listed, while people famous for a series of achievements have a broad summary. So it is reasonable to ask why they (seem to have) failed in a specific instance. Of course one may not get a good answer...

Comment: @WillSawin : Interesting; I overlooked that (sub)page. I see that it exists for 2018 and 2014, but I can't find it for other years. In particular, I can't find it for 1990 (Witten's year). Can you?

Comment: @TimothyChow The Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal has all of them, but I don't know where they sourced them from. For all the years up to 1986, you can get the same information by clicking on the names. So 1990 - 2010 is the period it seems to be missing on the website.

Comment: @WillSawin : Thanks! That Wikipedia page's entry for Witten is strange. Witten's "citation" is placed in quotation marks, with a footnote directing the reader to Atiyah's laudatio, but Atiyah's laudatio does not contain the phrase in quotation marks.

Comment: I went to our library to look at the book "International Mathematical Congresses: An Illustrated History 1893-1986," by Albers, Alexanderson, and Reid. At the end of the book it gives photos of all the medalists up to 1986, with a little blurb underneath each photo. This appears to be the source for Wikipedia and the mathunion website. But the book gives no indication that these are "official citations." I would hazard a guess that one of the authors of the book just made them up.

Comment: @TimothyChow Good find! So there are really a few different mysteries here. (1) did the authors of that book have an earlier source (official or not), or did they just make it up? (2) Where did the citations on Wikipedia 1990 - 2002 come from? (3) Where did the citations on Wikipedia 2006 - 2010 come from? I split (3) off because these citations exactly match the style of the later citations, making it more likely they came from the same source.

Comment: @TimothyChow I definitely agree that the Witten citation and some or all of the Wikipedia citations in the years 1990 - 2002 are not from any official source. The talk page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Fields_Medal/Archive1 contains some helpful information: First that in an earlier version, Witten's citation was different, and second that the table was created in part to answer a request for an explanation of what each Fields medal was given for, not for an official explanation.  Also, the citation for Lions is clearly an excerpt from a longer summary, not a standalone sentence.

Comment: @TimothyChow In fact this column of the Wikipedia page seems to incorporate information from many different sources in a way that could be deceptive. Emmanuel Kowalski has a copy of the '94 proceedings and has verified that Bourgain's and Zelmanov's "citations" come from the first sentence of their laudatios, while Yoccoz's does not (and thinks Yoccoz's may not be a good summary). I think the Wikipedia page should be edited to explain the different sources - I might get started on this.

Comment: I don't know if this is recent, but the Wikipedia page starts by saying that he was awarded the Fields Medal 'for his 1981 proof of the positive energy theorem in general relativity': this is obviously incorrect as the essay by Atiyah explains that he was awarded the prize for a range of mathematical contributions.